# GAE Datastore Large Amounts of Data

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, mysql

**Background:**

I'm working on a project that's starting out with a large SQL dump that I have to import to a new database.  This dump is about 1.5GB of just plain text, so quite a lot of information.  My client right now wants me to use Google App Engine and its datastore, which I'm (a) not so fond of and (b) doesn't really play well with SQL dumps.  Before I go through the trouble to make that happen...

**Question:**

What is a cloud-hosted database solution that can efficiently handle large quantities of data (and ideally is lower-cost)?  In particular, which would be a database solution to which I could just import my SQL dump as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your client has any reasons to use the datastore? If you already have the SQL dump, I think it would be easier to use [Google Cloud Sql](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) from GAE.

Comment: Thank you, I was previously unaware of this.